# How to use taskqueues with GAE 1.7.7 behind a proxy

Tags: google-app-engine

I upgraded to GAE 1.7.7 today and found out that task queues stopped working on my development setup.

I'm using https on my development environment through an nginx set up to proxy the connections from fakedomain.local:80 and fakedomain.local:443 to localhost:8080 (where GAE listens).

With this setup, taskqueues end up being created to be executed at fakedomain.local:80. This used to work because the request would be picked up by nginx, but the version 1.7.7 of the development server seems to have a port registry which won't serve a request unless the port is known (if I understand google.appengine.tools.devappserver2.Dispatcher._resolve_target correctly). Of course, GAE listens on port 8080 and my tasks marked to run on fakedomain.local:80 never get executed (GAE logs this error: An error occured while sending the task "task1" (Url: "...") in queue...).

I tried patching dispatcher.py:577 so instead of raising a ServerDoesNotExistError when the port is not known it will just use the default server. With this modification I can get the taskqueues running again, but I'd rather use a solution which doesn't involve changing GAE's code.

How can I make GAE register the port 80 and 443 in version 1.7.7? Alternatively, is there a way I could specify the complete target URL for the task? (ie fakedomain.local:8080/my_task, instead of just /mytask).

Comment: I ran into a similar error, when i tried to test my frontend with my gae backend. Did you find any solution for this ?

Comment: I didn´t find an official solution, so patching GAE was the only way I could get it working. AFAIK this might be related to the environment, because I have seen it happen on some setups but not others. There´s also a new release of GAE which I haven´t checked, maybe it´s fixed in the new one...

Answer (score 0):

`taskqueue.add(target=taskqueue.DEFAULT_APP_VERSION, ...)`
will run it on your default app, which should do exactly what you want.

`taskqueue.DEFAULT_APP_VERSION` => 
`app_identity.get_default_version_hostname()` =>
`environ['DEFAULT_VERSION_HOSTNAME']` =>
`'%s:%s' % (environ['SERVER_NAME'], server_port)`